# How do I get ARF video to play in webex?

Tags: wine, webex

I have webex installed on ubuntu 12.04 with wine as per the instructions at [this link](http://my.opera.com/rembrant/blog/2011/11/16/installing-webex-player-on-ubuntu-11-04-arf).

I'm able to open .arf files but the video is not showing up.  This is the output i get when i open the application using terminal

```
wine: Call from 0x7b839cf2 to unimplemented function msvcp90.dll.??0?$basic_stringstream@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z, aborting
```

EDIT : i'm trying to play an .arf file - the file works fine on windows but on my setup in ubuntu it is not working.

Comment: Is using another player like VLC an alternative?

Comment: doesn't look like it ... tried googling a little bit.

Comment: by the way I tried installing VLC player on wine. That is working fine.

Comment: Have you installed Webex player in Ubuntu?

Comment: VLC is available natively, no need for it to use wine.

Comment: @Mitch - i have installed webex player on ubuntu ontop of wine (that is using the windows installer file).

Comment: @UriHerrera - i was trying to see if my video was playing on a vlc installation on wine so that I could see whether it is an issue with this application or the wine configuration itself.

Comment: No, I meant install it for Ubuntu, without using wine?

Comment: @Mitch - as far as i'm aware, there is no version of webex for ubuntu. Hence i'm trying to install using wine

Comment: Actually, there is a Linux version.  You can [download it here](http://www.johnoriordan.ie/index.php/2008/03/10/webex-player-on-linux/)

Comment: @Mitch - got that setup but its not opening my arf file. any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

I'ld say rather than going with wine..

To play .arf files, convert them to mp4 format using the nbr2mp4 converter

1. Download nbr2mp4 tar file from this repo.

   http://webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html
2. After you download, create a directory for the installation(I'm doing it in ~/arf

   in this example) , now , extract the tar file into this folder.
3. Move to this folder.

   ```
    cd ~/arf/nbr2_mp4
   ```
4. Now set executable permissions to nbr2mp4.sh file.

   ```
    chmod +x ./nbr2mp4.sh
   ```
5. Now install the convertor by typing this command.

   ```
    ./nbr2mp4.sh
   ```
6. Type the directory where you want to install the software.

   Or rather, you may hit enter to install it in the current directory.
7. That's it, you can convert the arf files of webex to mp4 using this command.

   ```
    ./nbr2mp4 path/file-name.arf path-to-output-folder FPS
   ```

   Ex : ./nbr2mp4  ~/Downloads/research-talk.arf  ./  5

   A file called research-talk.mp4 will be created in the current directory.

The value of FPS can range from 3-10. The quality of the video is directly proportional to FPS.

Source : http://rodrigoguarischi.com/how-to-play-arf-file-on-ubuntu-12-04-linux/

Comment: The uk-dev.webex.com path required a login that I did not know.  I think I have found the same file at http://www.webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html though.  Thank you for the instructions.

Comment: Glad that helped! :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Install WINE
2. Download the MSI installer from the webex web-site http://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html
3. Right click on it and install using WINE
4. Run the player from the terminal
   wine "/home/username/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/WebEx/WebEx/500/nrplay.exe"

Answer (score 1):

Install winetricks and run:

```
winetricks vcrun2008
```

**Source:** http://wine.1045685.n5.nabble.com/Bug-29392-New-i-cant-run-game-www-jugger-ru-will-be-very-preciate-if-you-can-help-out-td5089008.html

Comment: @Eliah Kagan - tried this out, still getting the same problem. this installed visual c++ on wine.

Answer (score 1):

The tool does not like any *whitespace*, neither in the directory path where it is residing nor the MP4 directory. The directory path and filename of the file to be converted must not contain  any whitespace either.

So no whitespace anywhere -)