# Converting an ARF file using nbr2mp4 with Kubuntu 13.10

Tags: kubuntu, video-conversion

I followed the [NBR2MP4 converter procedure](http://www.webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html) on the WebEx site and also reviewed the step-by step instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/362719/219130 but no matter what I do, it just doesn't work (i.e. doesn't output any MP4 file).

From within the nbr2_mp4 directory:

```
$ ./nbr2mp4 my_file.arf /tmp/ 5
Converting /home/username/nbr2_mp4/my_file.arf to /tmp/my_file.mp4
Retrieving video data, fps=5...
```

I tried many different options with or without DEST and FPS, with and without sudo, and whatever I do, it just doesn't output any file, ever.

On the WebEx site it says `Linux OS: 32-bit Ubuntu 8.10/9.04` so it might simply be that the scripts are incompatible with 13.10, but I'd rather know if others have the same issue too?

Answer (score 4):

nbr2mp4 converter comes with the libraries it requires but doesn't read them from the directory.

Just run

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='./'
```

to let nbr2mp4 'see' it's own libraries.

Then the converter can be run as

```
nbr2mp4 XXX.arf
```

To make sure that the conversion is in progress check if one of `/tmp/wbx_nbr*.h264` files size is increasing.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Comment: I installed nbr2mp4 in /opt/ directory, have the same issue as OP. Then I did what you've written here, but it didn't help. I don't see any output file, I don't see any file in /tmp/ directory, like nbr2mp4 still doesn't work.

Comment: After installation of libraries which @Dej has written in his answer, nbr2mp4 works.
However, I have a .wrf, not .arf file and receive error saying "Cannot convert recording file because it is not a valid file format. Specify an Advanced Recording Format file (.arf)."

Answer (score 4):

In my case, in Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64 I still needed these 32-bit libraries:

`sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386`

I found out which libraries I needed by

1. trying to run ./nbr_play
2. looking for the missing library with dpkg -S (e.g. `dpkg -S
   libpangoxft-1.0.so.0`)
3. installing the library in its :i386 version.

But that was much more difficult than just downloading the windows player msi from https://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html and running it inside wine (and I still receive an mmap allocation error):

`wine msiexec /i path/to/nbr2player.msi`

The program is called Network Recording Player and should end up in your application menu.

Comment: I can get the `nbr2mp4` to work, but need to wrap it with `xvfb-run` since it's on an Ubuntu server with no display.  However it runs extremely slowly.  Did you need to wrap it with `xvfb-run` as well?

Comment: No. I used it in a real X environment. I don't recall whether it was hanging or slow.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case, some libraries required by nbr_play (the actual binary executed by nbr2mp4->nbrplay->nbr_play; nbr2mp4 and nbrplay are shell scripts). Just installing the missing libraries solved the problem.

You can check for missing libraries with 'ldd nbr_play'.

Also be aware that nbr_play is a 32-bit program. If you are using a 64-bit system, there is a chance that you already have installed the 64-bit versions of the libraries but not the 32-bit versions. In such a case you must install the 32-bit version of the libraries too.

The reason why the linker errors (unresolved libraries) are not shown when you execute the command is because the errors are redirected to /dev/null in the shell scripts mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install nbr2mp4 , which anyways didnt work on my Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. To Play .arf file , do following

1> Download nbr2player.msi (yes, windows installer) from webex link above or google it.

2> Right click and choose Open with option and then choose , "Find New Applcaition"

3> Ubuntu will suggest Q4Wine for the application, install it.

4> Now have your, Q4Wine know the path of downloaded msi file and install the nbr player.

5> Open nbr player using super key and browse to arf file and viola, play it.

Additional optional step :
Above steps works, but in case dependencies were still missing for Q4wine , install winetricks

sudo apt-get install winetricks

Retry 5 steps.