# Anyone know how to play .arf files in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, webex

How to play .arf Webex files on ubuntu 20.04. I've followed previous answers on ask.ubuntu but they are not working anymore. Please any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: All the information I can find says there are only tools for Windows and Mac to play these files. https://www.lifewire.com/arf-file-4140760 As the file type is a Cisco file type maybe they can help.

Comment: ' I've followed previous answers'.  Could you be more specific and detail why it didn't work?

Comment: I'm not able to download the nbr2mp4 tar file. could you please help? @MarcVanhoomissen

Comment: Could you please share the command that downloads the nbr2mp4 tar file @MarcVanhoomissen

Comment: You could have a look at this to get Webex application on Ubuntu:  https://help.webex.com/en-US/article/9vstcdb/Webex-for-Linux#Cisco_Reference.dita_9e0500f7-bc62-4d56-a60c-01bd398241c1 Not sure if this will allow you to read .arf files, however.

Comment: I just want to convert arf files to mp4. I'm following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/170259/how-do-i-get-arf-video-to-play-in-webex    but here the issue is I'm not able to download the nbr2mp4 tar file using the command "wget http://webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html". If you know the command, please share @MarcVanhoomissen

Comment: Please help @MarcVanhoomissen

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/311713/631600).

Comment: The link you refer to is incorrect. It seems there is no replacement for nbr2mp4.  Did you try to install the Webex app as explained in my former comment?  I have no better, unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to run it using Wine - check https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8490 .